# Poor Carbonation

Tags: yeast

Simpley stout from midwest supplies:tested bottle after 1 week. Sharp sparkeling bubbles like soda no foam. Oily residue on top after bubbles dissapate. Did add safe ale 05 to botteling bucket used belgian candi drops in bottels. Save it or pitch it??

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you edit your question and include the original and final gravity, and the amount of sugar, and the size of your bottles. Also, how (at what temperature) did you store the bottle?

Comment: Agree with @Robert - also, may want to give it another week or two.

Comment: was this an extract batch?

Answer (score 3):

One week is a little early for any bottle.  I'd wait a couple more weeks before making a determination on keeping or chucking it.

Answer (score 0):

Bottled beer is best conditioned for at least a month after it has been bottled. The bottle should have been stored at or about room temperature for a few weeks during that time. There is no use storing/condtioning the bottle in (say) a fridge or cold cellar for the whole time. I have found that conditioned beers I initially thought were "bad" improved amazingly over the course of 6 months to a year - to the point where friends asked for them in preference to "good" beers.

One problem with some kits is that the amount of malt supplied can be rather low (to keep costs down) and so the beer can lack body and head retention. If so that can be easily cured by adding more malt (extract) to the brew - especially wheat malt extract. If that does not suit the style of beer required then body can be improved by adding more barley malt extract or even just maltodextrin.

IMHO there is rarely any need to add extra yeast at the bottling stage to produce carbonation. The yeast still in suspension (don't worry its there) will usually do the job just as well.